# Merge statement but update only if exactly *one* row matches

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running a [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm) statement but I want the update to happen only if there is exactly *one* row matching.

```
merge into mergetest using dual on (a = 1)
  when matched then update set b = b+1;
```

I know I can include a `where` clause at the end, but I have no idea what to do. Group functions are not allowed, so `count(*) = 1` doesn't work.

Comment: Unless you introduce some form of serialization (e.g. locking), there's nothing stopping another session inserting a row *after* your code starts - and this is true whether you use a merge, or a select + update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PL/SQL this could be solved in the following way:

```
select count(*) into l_count from mergetest  where a = 1;

case l_count
  when 0 then
    insert into mergetest  (a,b) values (1,1);
  when 1 then
    update  mergetest  set b = b + 1 where a = 1;
  else
    NULL;
  end case;
```

Comment: Not bad, but if another session inserts into the table and commits between the `select` and the `case`, this will fail.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp AFAIK the merge statement has the same problem. The answer is: transactions

Comment: No, the merge is atomic.

Comment: A link to a comment has little weight - I could link to one of the followup comments that contradict it. Oracle docs or a reliable test case would carry some weight.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I would appreciate a link to Oracle documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I was incorrect to say "atomic" - that's a different concept. I meant "isolated". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Comment: After reflection: you're right, the merge can only see data committed at the start of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
merge into mergetest
    using (select a, count(*) as cnt
           from mergetest
           where a = 1
           group by a
          ) mt
          on mergetest.a = mt.a and cnt = 1
   when matched then
        update set b = b + 1;
```

Comment: This looks complicated. I'm actually running the query in plsql and an easy way would be to check for matches first and then do an `if-then-else`. I would only do it in plain SQL if there is an elegant solution.

Comment: @Roland . . . Given what you want to do, a subquery that counts the rows for a given value of `a` doesn't seem inelegant.  It seems necessary, whether done in a `merge` or a PL/SQL block.

Comment: See my answer on how to do it with PL/SQL:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28383194/480894

Comment: @Roland . . . I'm pretty sure that in a `merge` statement, the `using` clause is evaluated only once.  However, you would need to look at the execution plan to guarantee it.

Comment: There is one problem with your solution. What if you want to add a not matched clause to insert in case there are 0 matching rows? How do you differentiate this case from the case of more than one matching row?

Comment: Also consider that the select in the using clause will not return anything if there is no match. In this case even an existing `when not matched` clause is not executed.