# Case based on select statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql, case

Instead of doing:

```
select count(*) into l_count from mergetest  where a = 1;

case l_count
  when 0 then
    insert into mergetest  (a,b) values (1,1);
  when 1 then
    update  mergetest  set b = b + 1 where a = 1;
  else
    NULL;
  end case;
```

I would like to get rid of the local variable `l_count` and instead do:

```
case select count(*) from mergetest where a = 1;
...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. It's not related to PL/SQL's CASE *control structure* but rather to PL/SQL in general. You can't use it in an IF statement either.

So this code wouldn't compile either:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE) > 0 THEN ...
```

Note that you *can* use subqueries if the CASE statement is an *expression* within a SELECT (or similar SQL) statement:

```
SEELCT
  p.name,
  CASE WHEN P.TYPE_ID = 1 THEN
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM child c WHERE c.parent_id = p.id)
    ELSE 0
  END cnt
FROM parent p;
```

But of course, within an expression you cannot use statements such as INSERT or UPDATE.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get rid of local variable by using `merge`, not `case`:

```
merge into mergetest
  using (select 1 a from dual) ins
  on (mergetest.a = ins.a)
  when matched then 
    update set mergetest.b = mergetest.b + 1
      where (select count(1) from mergetest where mergetest.a = ins.a)  = 1
  when not matched then insert (mergetest.a, mergetest.b)
    values (ins.a, 1)
```

Line:

```
      where (select count(1) from mergetest where mergetest.a = ins.a)  = 1
```

prevents updates if `a` already exists in table more than one time.

Comment: True, but the code becomes harder to understand. You answered my other question btw: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382332/merge-statement-but-update-only-if-exactly-one-row-matches

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is not possible using `PL/SQL`

from the doc

> The value of the CASE operand and WHEN operands in a simple CASE
>   statement can be any PL/SQL type other than BLOB, BFILE, an object
>   type, a PL/SQL record, an index-by table, a varray, or a nested table.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm

However, you can use `scalar subquery`

```
select case when dummy = 'X' then (select count(*) from all_users)
else (select count(*) from dual) 
end cnt from dual
```

Which would probably resolve your issue.

Comment: I get an error message:

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev